# startWith value is null the first time, even with non null first selection. why?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have a group dropdown, and when selecting from the drop down the first time, the startWith value is always null. Why is this happening? In subsequent selection from dropdown, startWith() gets the right value.

So selecting from dropdown drives this list.

My template looks something like this:

```
<person-list
    [list]=list$
</person-list>
```

My component class

```
ngOnInit() {
    list$ = this.getNames();
}

getNames():Observable<Name[]> {

    return formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(formControl.value),
    switchMap(group => {
       return http.getNames();
    })
 )}
```

Comment: But where you init form control values? (you know that list$ = this.getNames(); << this lines runs before constructor and onInit)

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, it runs in ngOnInit()

Comment: Please show the minimum code to reproduce the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We don't know what that form control is or what it's connected to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should just subscribe your Observable
this.getNames().subscribe(names => list$=names)

Answer (score 0):

Need context in this question. Because initially formControl.value might be undefined. Make sure to patch the value first to formControl.value. By the way you can just test without formControl, just use startWith('query').